# Predicting score from text data and non-text data

Tags: python

This is for an assignment. I have ~100 publications on a dummy website. Each publication has been given an artificial score indicating how successful it is. I need to predict what affects that value.

So far, I've scraped the information that might affect the score and saved them into individual lists. The relevant part of my loop looks like:

for publicationurl:

Predictor 1 = 3.025

Predictor 2 = Journal A

Predictor 3 = 0

Response Variable = 42.5

Title = Sentence

Abstract = Paragraph

I can resolve most of that by putting predictors 1-3 and the response into a dataframe then doing regression. The bit that is tripping me up is the Title and Abstract text. I can strip them of punctuation and remove stopwords, but after that I'm not sure how to actually analyse them alongside the other predictors. I was looking into doing some kind of text-similarity comparison between high-high and high-low scoring pairs and basing whether the title and abstract affect the score based off of that, but am hoping there is a much neater method that allows me to actually put that text into a predictive model too.

I currently have 5 predictors besides the text and there are ~40,000 words in total across all titles and abstracts if any of that affects what kind of method works best. Ideally I'd like to end up being able to put everything into a single predictive model, but any method that can lead me to a working solution is good.

Comment: This looks like an introduction to ML/AI exercise? Have you looked into naive Bayes? Using Sklearn for example you could "easily" predict the class 'good', 'bad' from the abstract. The accuracy won't be amazing but might be more than enough for the scope of the assignment. If you go down this road look for an example that does email spam prediction which you can basically copy/paste.
I now read that the score was assigned arbitrarily, that will mess up this and basically any other method since your model wont be able to find any common pattern between good/bad articles.

Comment: @picklepick Arbitrarily was a poor choice of word. I'll edit the post to artificial. I meant that the scores were created by the professor for the purpose of the assignment, rather than being based on real-world data- I assume they have some form of basis in the content of the page.

Answer (score 0):

This would be an ideal situation for using Multinomial Naive Bayes. This is a relatively simple yet quite powerful method to classify the class of a text. If this is an introductory exercise I'm 99% sure that you're prof is expecting something with NB to solve the given problem.

I would recommend a library like [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html) which should make the task almost trivial. If you're interested in the intuition behind NB, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2L2Uv9pdDA) YouTube video should serve as a good introduction.
Start off by going over some examples/blog posts, google should provide you with countless examples. Then modify the code to fit your use case.
You could either group the articles in two classes e.g. `score <=5 = bad`, `score > 5 = good`. A next step would be to predict more than two classes like explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142505/how-to-use-naive-bayes-for-multi-class-problems).